# Bayesian a posteriori law of bernouilli law, from observed correlated bernouilli law

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian

Suppose that you have $N$ people passing an exam having 2 yes/no questions.
After seeing the results of $N-1$ people and the result of the first question of the $Nth$ person, I want to know what I can infer for the second question.

I modelize the question’s results by two bernoulli laws $X_1 = B(p_1)$ and $X_2 = B(p_2)$. Each person has his own $p_1, p_2$ but we think that they’re linked. I’m looking for a way to use this dependence …

So far, I have chosen an a priori law on $p_1, p_2$ : the $beta(1,1)$ function for both. We know that if a person answers with $S$ success and $E$ errors for the first question, the a posteriori law will be $beta(1+S, 1+E)$. But we don’t know anything about how it changes $p2$.
My guess is that $p2$ could be something like $beta(1+kS, 1+kE)$ with $k$ a coefficient representing how much the first question and second question are correlated. This intuition comes from the facts that if the questions are independent then the a posteriori law of $p_2$ is still $beta(1,1)$ and if they are perfectly correlated, the a posteriori law of $p_2$ is $beta(1+S, 1+E)$.

What about in between ?
Any references/books/etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll need to move this question to stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com -- the readers of StackOverflow probably won't have much to say about this. EDIT: my advice about problems of this kind is to go ahead and formulate the integrals that are needed for whatever probability, and then see what you can do to solve them. If you can't solve them by hand, try numerical approximation or try using a symbolic computation system or try asking for help specifically to solve the integrals.